# Anonymous inner class at member level

Tags: java

In the book 'Java OCP 8 Programmer II Study Guide', it is said that

> an anonymous inner class is a local inner class

and

> a local inner class is a nested class defined within a method

However, I am able to define an anonymous inner class outside a method:

```
public class Outer {
  Foo ex = new Foo {
      @Override
      public void bar() {
        System.out.println("This is my bar implementation");
      }
  }
}

void TestClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer outer = new Outer();
    outer.ex.bar();
  }
}
```

Is the book wrong in saying that an anonymous inner class is a local inner class as it doesn't have to be local (within a method) or is the example I provided not an anonymous inner class (as it is assigned to a named variable)?

Thanks

Comment: *"an anonymous inner class is a local inner class"* ... emphasis on *local*. An anonymous class expression is really like an inner class if it is defined in a non-static context because, like an inner class instance, its instances hold a reference to an enclosing instance.  However, if defined in a static context, an anonymous class expression is unlike an inner class because its instances hold no reference to an enclosing instance.  Nested inner class instances must always have an enclosing instance.  This is not true of either local or anonymous classes.

Comment: If the book says that, it's wrong. An anonymous inner class is both a definition and an implementation of some type.

Answer (score 0):

`ex` is not a local class. anything that a local class cannot be anonymous and vice-versa (to the best of my knowledge)

Quoting from [Oracle's Java OO tutorial on Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) :

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. **They are like local classes except that they do not have a name.** Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

Couple of lines below ..

> **While local classes are class declarations, anonymous classes are expressions**, which means that you define the class in another expression